# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()

Tags: android, graphics

```
public class SlimmingView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Paint paint1 = new Paint();
Bitmap bitmap;

Bitmap rotatedBitmap,SlimmingBitmap;


private int mPosX;
private int mPosY;

int screenWidth, screenHeight;

final int bitWidth, bitHeight;


int radius;

boolean isShow=false;

public SlimmingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    PathEffect effects = new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 8, 8,8, 8 }, 1);
    paint.setPathEffect(effects);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);


    paint1.setPathEffect(effects);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.meinv);



    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    screenHeight = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    screenWidth = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    mPosX = screenWidth / 2;
    mPosY = screenHeight / 2;

    bitWidth = screenWidth / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    bitHeight = screenHeight / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2 - 22;

    radius = 40;

    SlimmingBitmap=Slimming(bitmap,mPosX-20, mPosY-20,mPosX+20, mPosY+20, radius, 0.2f);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {



    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        isShow=true;

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {

        break;
    }

    }

    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    canvas.drawBitmap(SlimmingBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawCircle(mPosX-20, mPosY-20, radius, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(mPosX+20, mPosY+20, radius, paint1);
}

public Bitmap Slimming(Bitmap bmp,int startX,int startY ,int endX,int endY,int radius,float power)
{
    //int height = bmp.getHeight();
//  int width= bmp.getWidth();

//  Bitmap bmpSephia = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,bmp.getConfig());
//  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);

//  canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    for (int x = endX + radius; x > endX - radius && x > 0; x--)
    {
        for (int y = endY + radius; y > endY - radius && y > 0; y--)
        {
            if (x > bmp.getWidth() || y > bmp.getHeight())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Math.pow((x - endX), 2) + Math.pow((y -endY), 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2))
            {
                // not in the cic
                continue;
            }

            double LVF_Modulus = 1 - GetDistXDist(x,y, startX,startY) / (radius * radius);
            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * LVF_Modulus *  LVF_Modulus;

            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * power;

            double LVF_XPos = x - LVF_Modulus * (endX - startX);
            double LVF_YPos = y - LVF_Modulus * (endY - startY);

            long LVI_XPos1 = (long) (LVF_XPos);
            long LVI_XPos2 = LVI_XPos1 + 1;
            long LVI_YPos1 = (long)(LVF_YPos);
            long LVI_YPos2 = LVI_YPos1 + 1;

            if (LVI_XPos1 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos1 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos2 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos2 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_XPos2 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos2 < 0 )
                {
                    continue;
                }


            int LVI_RValue = 0;
            int LVI_GValue = 0;
            int LVI_BValue = 0;
             double temp1 = 0;
             double temp2 = 0;

            int c = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos1, (int)LVI_XPos1);
                // a= Color.alpha(c);
                int red = Color.red(c);
                int green = Color.green(c);
                int blue = Color.blue(c);

            int c1 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos1, (int)LVI_XPos2);  
            int red1 = Color.red(c1);
            int green1 = Color.green(c1);
            int blue1 = Color.blue(c1);

            int c2 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos2, (int)LVI_XPos1);  
            int red2 = Color.red(c2);
            int green2 = Color.green(c2);
            int blue2 = Color.blue(c2);


            int c3 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos2, (int)LVI_XPos2);  
            int red3 = Color.red(c3);
            int green3 = Color.green(c3);
            int blue3 = Color.blue(c3);

            temp1 = (red + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red1 - red));
            temp2 = (red2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red3 - red2));
            LVI_RValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (green + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green1 - green));
            temp2 = (green2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green3 - green2));
            LVI_GValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (blue + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue1 - blue));
            temp2 = (blue2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue3 - blue2));
            LVI_BValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            if (LVI_RValue> 255) {
                LVI_RValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_RValue < 0) {
                LVI_RValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_GValue > 255) {
                LVI_GValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_GValue < 0) {
                LVI_GValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_BValue > 255) {
                LVI_BValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_BValue < 0) {
                LVI_BValue = 0;
            }

            bmp.setPixel(y, x, Color.rgb(LVI_RValue, LVI_GValue, LVI_RValue));

        }
    }
    return bmp;
}

public double GetDistXDist( int Point1X,int Point1Y, int Point2X,int Point2Y)
{
    double dist2 = (Math.pow((Point1X - Point2X), 2) + Math.pow((Point1Y - Point2Y), 2));
    return dist2;
}
 }
```

In my code,i want to change area pixel of image, the area is common part of two  circle,

`int startX,int startY ,int endX,int endY` is the centres of two circles,But when i run the app,
It give me

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()
```

I donot know how to midify?

edit:

```
 public class SlimmingView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

Paint paint = new Paint();
Paint paint1 = new Paint();
Bitmap bitmap;

Bitmap rotatedBitmap,SlimmingBitmap;


private int mPosX;
private int mPosY;

int screenWidth, screenHeight;

 int bitWidth, bitHeight;


int radius;

boolean isShow=false;

public SlimmingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    PathEffect effects = new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 8, 8,8, 8 }, 1);
    paint.setPathEffect(effects);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);


    paint1.setPathEffect(effects);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    radius = 20;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.meinv);


}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {



    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        isShow=true;

        SlimmingBitmap=Slimming(bitmap,155, 235,165, 245, radius, 0.2f);
        invalidate();

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {

        break;
    }

    }

    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isShow)
       {canvas.drawBitmap(SlimmingBitmap, 0, 0, null);}
    canvas.drawCircle(155, 235, radius, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(165, 245, radius, paint1);
}

public Bitmap Slimming(Bitmap bmp,int startX,int startY ,int endX,int endY,int radius,float power)
{
    //int height = bmp.getHeight();
//  int width= bmp.getWidth();

//  Bitmap bmpSephia = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,bmp.getConfig());
//  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);

//  canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    for (int x = endX + radius; x > endX - radius && x > 0; x--)
    {
        for (int y = endY + radius; y > endY - radius && y > 0; y--)
        {
            if (x > bmp.getWidth() || y > bmp.getHeight())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Math.pow((x - endX), 2) + Math.pow((y -endY), 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2))
            {
                // not in the cic
                continue;
            }

            double LVF_Modulus = 1 - GetDistXDist(x,y, startX,startY) / (radius * radius);
            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * LVF_Modulus *  LVF_Modulus;

            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * power;

            double LVF_XPos = x - LVF_Modulus * (endX - startX);
            double LVF_YPos = y - LVF_Modulus * (endY - startY);

            long LVI_XPos1 = (long) (LVF_XPos);
            long LVI_XPos2 = LVI_XPos1 + 1;
            long LVI_YPos1 = (long)(LVF_YPos);
            long LVI_YPos2 = LVI_YPos1 + 1;

            if (LVI_XPos1 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos1 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos2 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos2 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_XPos2 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos2 < 0 )
                {
                    continue;
                }


            int LVI_RValue = 0;
            int LVI_GValue = 0;
            int LVI_BValue = 0;
             double temp1 = 0;
             double temp2 = 0;

            int c = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos1, (int)LVI_XPos1);
                // a= Color.alpha(c);
                int red = Color.red(c);
                int green = Color.green(c);
                int blue = Color.blue(c);

            int c1 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos1, (int)LVI_XPos2);  
            int red1 = Color.red(c1);
            int green1 = Color.green(c1);
            int blue1 = Color.blue(c1);

            int c2 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos2, (int)LVI_XPos1);  
            int red2 = Color.red(c2);
            int green2 = Color.green(c2);
            int blue2 = Color.blue(c2);


            int c3 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_YPos2, (int)LVI_XPos2);  
            int red3 = Color.red(c3);
            int green3 = Color.green(c3);
            int blue3 = Color.blue(c3);

            temp1 = (red + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red1 - red));
            temp2 = (red2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red3 - red2));
            LVI_RValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (green + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green1 - green));
            temp2 = (green2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green3 - green2));
            LVI_GValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (blue + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue1 - blue));
            temp2 = (blue2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue3 - blue2));
            LVI_BValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            if (LVI_RValue> 255) {
                LVI_RValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_RValue < 0) {
                LVI_RValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_GValue > 255) {
                LVI_GValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_GValue < 0) {
                LVI_GValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_BValue > 255) {
                LVI_BValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_BValue < 0) {
                LVI_BValue = 0;
            }

            bmp.setPixel(y, x, Color.rgb(LVI_RValue, LVI_GValue, LVI_RValue));

        }
    }
    return bmp;
}

public double GetDistXDist( int Point1X,int Point1Y, int Point2X,int Point2Y)
{
    double dist2 = (Math.pow((Point1X - Point2X), 2) + Math.pow((Point1Y - Point2Y), 2));
    return dist2;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the method it is Ok

```
public Bitmap Slimming(Bitmap bmp,int startX,int startY ,int endX,int endY,int radius,float power)
{
    //int height = bmp.getHeight();
//  int width= bmp.getWidth();

//  Bitmap bmpSephia = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,bmp.getConfig());
//  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpSephia);

//  canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    for (int x = endX + radius; x > endX - radius && x > 0; x--)
    {
        for (int y = endY + radius; y > endY - radius && y > 0; y--)
        {
            if (x > bmp.getWidth() || y > bmp.getHeight())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Math.pow((x - endX), 2) + Math.pow((y -endY), 2) > Math.pow(radius, 2))
            {
                // not in the cic
                continue;
            }

            double LVF_Modulus = 1 - GetDistXDist(x,y, startX,startY) / (radius * radius);
            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * LVF_Modulus *  LVF_Modulus;

            LVF_Modulus = LVF_Modulus * power;

            double LVF_XPos = x - LVF_Modulus * (endX - startX);
            double LVF_YPos = y - LVF_Modulus * (endY - startY);

            int LVI_XPos1 = (int)(LVF_XPos);
            int LVI_XPos2 = LVI_XPos1 + 1;
            int LVI_YPos1 = (int)(LVF_YPos);
            int LVI_YPos2 = LVI_YPos1 + 1;

            if (LVI_XPos1 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos1 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos2 >= bmp.getWidth() ||
                    LVI_YPos2 >= bmp.getHeight() ||
                    LVI_XPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos1 < 0 ||
                    LVI_XPos2 < 0 ||
                    LVI_YPos2 < 0 )
                {
                    continue;
                }


            int LVI_RValue = 0;
            int LVI_GValue = 0;
            int LVI_BValue = 0;
             double temp1 = 0;
             double temp2 = 0;

            int c = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_XPos1, (int)LVI_YPos1);
                // a= Color.alpha(c);
                int red = Color.red(c);
                int green = Color.green(c);
                int blue = Color.blue(c);

            int c1 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_XPos1, (int)LVI_YPos2);  
            int red1 = Color.red(c1);
            int green1 = Color.green(c1);
            int blue1 = Color.blue(c1);

            int c2 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_XPos2, (int)LVI_YPos1);  
            int red2 = Color.red(c2);
            int green2 = Color.green(c2);
            int blue2 = Color.blue(c2);


            int c3 = bmp.getPixel((int)LVI_XPos2, (int)LVI_YPos2);  
            int red3 = Color.red(c3);
            int green3 = Color.green(c3);
            int blue3 = Color.blue(c3);

            temp1 = (red + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red1 - red));
            temp2 = (red2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(red3 - red2));
            LVI_RValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (green + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green1 - green));
            temp2 = (green2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(green3 - green2));
            LVI_GValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            temp1 = (blue + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue1 - blue));
            temp2 = (blue2 + (LVF_XPos - LVI_XPos1)*(blue3 - blue2));
            LVI_BValue = (int)(temp1 + (LVF_YPos - LVI_YPos1)*(temp2 - temp1));

            if (LVI_RValue> 255) {
                LVI_RValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_RValue < 0) {
                LVI_RValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_GValue > 255) {
                LVI_GValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_GValue < 0) {
                LVI_GValue = 0;
            }

            if (LVI_BValue > 255) {
                LVI_BValue = 255;
            } else if (LVI_BValue < 0) {
                LVI_BValue = 0;
            }

            bmp.setPixel(y, x, Color.rgb(LVI_RValue, LVI_GValue, LVI_RValue));

        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view will not 'know' its size until the onMeasure() (or onLayout() and may change in onSizeChanged() too). You will need to get the View dimensions within these and not in the constructor.