# Bitmap set exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : x must be < bitmap.width()

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working with an image which has four color where each color perform different operation.Like,when i click on color red, it take pixel value through bitmap and if color get matched corresponding operation performed.But, now i am facing one problem like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()` So, i set bitmap height and width manually.

I have a table (row=2,column=19)  with 37 image button and one that image.1st row has one image and 18 image button and 2nd row has 19 image button.that is why if i set height and width of this image manually, different device that image takes space which i set by bitmap and other button get stretchered (it shows different screen different view).so,what should i have to do.can i set bitmap width and height manually.

```
bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.spdf3);
int width=102;
int height=71;
Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
spdf.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Comment: maybe you are trying to scale a bitmap which is already smaller than the width you have specified. Try to find out the bitmap width even before you hardcode the width it has to be scaled to.

Comment: you can see your solution in your error **x must be < bitmap.width()**

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789288/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-x-must-be-bitmap-width