# IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I  want  to crop an image with in a margin (10,50,10,50),(left,top,right,bottom) respectively of an imageview. Here is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgView.getWidth(),imgView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, (imgView.getLeft() + 10),
                imgView.getTop() + 50,imgView.getRight() - 10,imgView.getBottom() - 50);
bitmap.recycle();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
imgView.draw(canvas);
```

ie, if my imageview is of dimension 200X300.then i want to get the bitmap image with in the specified area only .When I am trying to do this It shows error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:410)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:383)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6790018/603744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and see if it works:

```
// using this method createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height)
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 10,
            50, imgView.getWidth() - 20, imgView.getHeight() - 100);
```

`getLeft` and others is used to get the position of the view in its parent. Not the dimension of the bitmap.

Comment: It cuts right and bottom part correctly.But not top and left.

Comment: well it should be correct, try to put `bitmap, 0 , 0 ,getWidth(), getHeight()` to see if the bitmap loaded is the original size.

Comment: Are you sure 10 and 50 is what you want? since my current solution offset is 10 and 50 which fit with what you want.

Comment: I drew a rectangle over imageview.It has a rect of             RectF drawRect = new RectF();
drawRect.set(imgView.getLeft()+10, imgView.getTop()+50, imgView.getRight()-10,imgView.getBottom() - 50);
canvas.drawRect(drawRect, paint);

Comment: ImageView has margin                                  android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="50dip"

Comment: could you please log and tell me the width and the height of the imageview/`bitmap`?

Comment: It is dynamic.But now width and height of imageView/bitmap is imgView.getWidth() = 450
imgView.getHeight() = 606

Answer (score 1):

```
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
            sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);
```

Like in lists, it starts from 0, so width must be bitmap width - 1.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your explanation but somehow this helped me with the same exception.